# Adding description to properties while generating JSON schema using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to add description attribute to properties?

I'm using json.net to generate schema:

```
var shema = new Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaGenerator();
var sh = shema.Generate(typeof(APIDocumentation.AlertDTO), false).ToString();
```

And I would like to add some simple documentation for user to understand what each field mean.
Right now I'm able to add description attribute to class using [JsonObject(Description = "my description")], but it can't be used with properties inside class. Is there a possiblity to do something like:

```
[JsonObject(Description = "My description")]
public class AlertDTO
{
    [SomeAttribute(Description="Property description")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

Or maybe there is a way to take VS style comments and add them to JSON schema as description?

Comment: did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Description attribute from the System.ComponentModel namespace.

Took me a while to find, but there is an example in the documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateWithDescriptions.htm